# All variables active on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, products, frontend, drop-downs

On the product pages only 1 dropdown should be active.  All of mine are active.  No idea why.  Please help.

See here: http://www.gsworkwear.com/portwest-wakefield-trousers-2085.html

Very URGENT.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about the configurable product's options drop downs? If that is the case, these are necessary for the purchase to be made as they are required to be specified for the correct product to be added to the cart.

Could you be more specific about what exactly you are looking to not be on the product page?

Comment: This is correct but they shouldn't ALL be active at the same time. I should have to pick from the first attribute before selecting the second.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem.  It turns out that a theme we were running has a problem if the swatches aren't setup fully.  As a result it allowed all of the dropdowns to be used at once.  Swatches disabled all works now as expected.